# Using sfDoctrineActAsTaggablePlugin, how to get the list of tags + the number of contents they tag?

Tags: php, symfony1, tags, symfony-1.4

`PluginTagTable::getAllTagNameWithCount()` gets me the list of tags, but I need to add a condition on the Contents the tags are tagged to.

How do I get the list of tags + the number of contents, where `content.state_id = 3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer in apostrophe plugin :

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('Tagging tg, tg.Tag t, Content c');
$q->andWhere('c.id = tg.taggable_id and c.state_id = ?', 3);

$this->tagsInOrder = PluginTagTable::getAllTagNameWithCount($q,Array('model' => 'Content', 'sort_by_popularity' => true));
```